# Unable to add application assignment using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

When creating a request to assign an app to an AD group in Azure Intune using the graph API, i get the following response.

```
 {  "error": {
"code": "ModelValidationFailure",
"message": "Cannot create an abstract class.",
"innerError": {
  "message": "Cannot create an abstract class.",
  "request-id": "removed",
  "date": "removed"
}  }}
```

and here's my post data

```
{ "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment", "intent": "required", "target": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget", "groupId": "removed"  }, "settings": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignmentSettings"}}
```

Here's the reference i've used to generate the json data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-apps-mobileappassignment-create?view=graph-rest-beta

And I'm not sure if it something to do with my json input or if the graph api endpoint has an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignmentSettings](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/intune-apps-mobileappassignmentsettings.md) is an abstract class. You'll need to provide a concrete implementation of assignment settings e.g. [microsoftStoreForBusinessAppAssignmentSettings](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/intune-apps-microsoftstoreforbusinessappassignmentsettings.md) or [iosStoreAppAssignmentSettings](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/intune-apps-iosstoreappassignmentsettings.md).

Your post data in this case could be:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppAssignment",
  "intent": "required",
  "target": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget",
    "groupId":"removed"
  },
  "settings": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.microsoftStoreForBusinessAppAssignmentSettings",
    "useDeviceContext":"true"
  }
}
```